# 600 visitors per day, 20 backlinks but still not referenced by Google

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, ranking, robots.txt

i've launch a website on wednesday (9 August)

There's already in 4 days

- 12,000 viewed pages
- 1,400 visits
- 20 to 25 backlincks
- a sitemap.xml (130 URL)
- english language / french language - url like that "/en/"  "/fr/"

BUT, i'm still not referrenced by google

In the google webmaster i have 
0 backlinks
130 in sitemap, 0 URL referrenced on google

For a smaller website, i remember that i took me less to appear on google with less visits.

My url is: http://www.seek-team.com/en/ for english and juste replace /en/ by /fr/ to access it in french.

**What's causing this ? Is there an explanation ?**
Thanks for your help

(ps, i've already checked robots.txt)

Comment: When posting links can you post the full link rather than a shortened one.

Comment: You've given lots of details, but have not clearly asked a question. Are you interested in knowing why you aren't yet appearing in Google search results?

Comment: definitly i want to know what's causing this. I use shortened links on this forum to avoid being referrenced on stackexchange. ;)

Comment: patience is a virtue, my friend :)

Comment: @Tristan: Actually, posting the full link would not make a difference, if Google followed the shortened link then it would find your site anyway.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Google won't follow it either way, Links on SE are nofollow.

Comment: @Noctrine: Actually search engines DO follow 'nofollow' links, they just don't count them in PageRank. Regardless, it makes no difference to the shortened argument.

Comment: I am facing the same proble with my site http://article-stack.com
It cached my site in starting. I was able to find 6 backlinks to my site through google. Suddenly it stopped to cache my site. Even now it shows only 5 back links.

My domain is around 4-5 months old. I had written articles to other sites as well. But google is not able to search those links as well. Link for external article is
amitguptagwl.sulekha.com/blog/post/2010/08/why-to-support-hacking.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hard to say for sure why you aren't indexed yet but:

1) Number of visitors has no bearing whatsoever on your indexing or rankings. Google doesn't know this information and, even if it they did, it really offers nothing in terms of relevance of any page for search.

2) 20 backlinks is hardly a lot. Even then, unless Google knows about those backlinks they are useless (for SEO). Those backlinks may be on pages that aren't indexed by Google, may be "nofollow", or on sites that Google has devalued as link farms. Basically quantity of links that you know about != quantity or quality of links in Google's eyes.

3) Two days is hardly enough time to expect to be indexed. Yes, some sites appear quicker then that but there are lots of factors that affect that. Those sites may have had a high quality link pointing to them or something else that led Google to them quickly.

Be patient. Search engine rankings don't happen overnight. Focus on improving your site and promoting it. Good content and natural links will go a lot further then hawking the search engines looking for your rankings. If your site is good it will bhe indexed soon and ranked well in time.

Comment: it can take upwards of 4-6 months to show up in google's search results. i say this from experience.

Answer (score 5):

If you do a google search right now:

```
site:seek-team.com
```

You will see that google already have indexed at least some of your pages.

Comment: Exactly. I know Google is awesome but does anyone really think that even close to 130 pages out of the *millions* created every day should be indexed within just 4 days?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: No. 4 days is much too long. Usually Google is a lot faster than that.

Comment: @Sylver: Not for new sites, nor for un-updated sites.

Answer (score 4):

I had a site with far more links from other reputable, well trafficked sites that took several weeks to be indexed.  And it was first caught by Bing, not Google, despite Google's far more prolific crawler.  Go figure.

There's a concept called "Domain Aging."  Nobody knows exactly what the various search engines look for, but several surmise that older, more established domains are given preference.  If your domain is brand new and literally just registered, it's likely very low priority on Google's "to do's" list.  Time is all that could solve this one, if the theory is correct.

Use your time waiting to install Google Webmaster tools and the associated tool from Bing.  Analyze the living daylights out of it.  Put up a valid sitemap, ensure that you're using properly validated semantic markup (you're currently showing 7 w3 errors)  Update the meta tags (description is currently blank).  Adding Google Analytics is an outstanding way to see where your traffic is coming from and where they are going....an added benefit is that careful daily analysis can help you detect hack attempts, believe it or not.

It looks like you're doing a good job on Social media integration too.  I mention this because my most successful clients get an order of magnitude more traffic from outside links and social media than they do from all the search engines combined.  So, get active on Twitter and Facebook, and promote every update you make.  Judging by your current traffic without any search engine records, you're well on your way.

Good luck.  Nice looking site!

Comment: To whomever downvoted me:  thanks.  Next time, how about giving a reason?

Comment: +1 I have also read about this domain name age thing. They call it google sandbox.